# Using Quickfix list, how to add a line/string to a certain line number of each file

Tags: command-line, quickfix

Scenario: I've got 4 files in my Quickfix list and I want to add a new line, `"status": "not started",` onto line 5 of each of them.

I tried this:

`cfdo norm 5GO"status": "not started",`

Which I thought would work on each file, move to line 5, `O` adds an empty line, and then I'm adding my text. But this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: can you try `:cfdo :call append(4, '"status": "not started"')`?

Comment: Try escaping the double quotes. Sometimes vims command line thinks they are comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters there are two decent options here.

Regarding the path I started on, as [@D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) intimated, the escaping was important but I used singles around the doubles instead.

I also used 'execute' so I could wrap the whole thing as a string. Not sure if that was needed or not?

So

```
:cfdo execute 'norm 5GO"status": "not started",' | update
```

worked, as did [@Christian's](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt)

```
:cfdo :call append(4, '"status": "not started"')
```

Comment: Please accept your answer if it solved your problem to resolve the question.